# Given a ggplot2 object, can I detect whether axes are discrete?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given either the `gg` object or the `gg_b` object, below, is it possible to detect, for each axis, whether the variable mapped onto the axes is discrete?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

gg <- 
  mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), hp)) +
  geom_point()

gg_b <- ggplot_build(gg)
```

I want to the able to do this as part of supporting an  organizational style on graphics.

**SOLUTION** (ht/baptiste)

```
has_discrete_axis <-
  function(gg) {
    gg_b <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(gg)
    lapply(gg_b$layout$panel_scales, 
           function(s) inherits(s[[1]], "ScaleDiscrete"))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
lapply(gg_b$layout$panel_scales, function(s) inherits(s[[1]], "ScaleDiscrete"))
```

Comment: Thank you... I had looked around in $data and $plot, but wasn't seeing any evidence of the ad hoc factor, other than the label.